# Can I transfer my forked repository to another github account without losing hisotry?

Tags: github, fork

I forked a repo and push some pieces of code in that repo. Now I want to transfer that forked repo to another account without losing the piece of code and git history.

Can I do that or do I have to look for another solution?

I didn't try anything right now...

looking for experienced one